# SQL Server : cannot drop table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, drop-table

I try to drop all the foreign and primary keys for an assignment, but so far I get the following error:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   'fk_DEPENDENT_ESSN' is not a constraint.
>
> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Here are my commands:

```
Use Company;
Go

--Dropping FKs from Dependent Table
ALTER TABLE Dependent
DROP fk_DEPENDENT_ESSN

--Dropping FKs from Dept_Locations Table
ALTER TABLE Dept_Locations
DROP fk__DEPT_LOCATIONS__Dnumber

--Dropping FKs from Employee Table
ALTER TABLE Employee
DROP FK__Employee__Dno

ALTER TABLE Employee
DROP FK__Employee__Super___ssn

--Dropping FKs from Project Table
ALTER TABLE Project
DROP FK__Project

--Dropping FKs from WORKS_ON Table
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON
DROP FK__WORKS_ON__Essn

ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON
DROP FK__WORKS_ON__PNO
```

How should I fix this, sorry I can't post my database on here. if you have any questions, feel free to comment or we can email.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't show your schema, it may not be possible to get a precise answer.

Comment: You need to show to script on creating your table structures, so that we can evaluate those keys.

Comment: how should I post my schema on here

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` statements that created the tables!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `fk_DEPENDENT_ESSN` does not exist. Are you missing and underscore? Should be `fk__DEPENDENT_ESSN`?

You can check what the names of the FK are using the `sysobjects` table.

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '%DEPENDENT_ESSN'
```

See [SQL Server 2008 cannot drop constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671345/sql-server-2008-cannot-drop-constraint)

Comment: Thanks can I email you? kind hard to put a lot of stuff on here. or can I?

Comment: @LinWei Just run the query I posted, it will check the schema. If it finds a row it will show you the correct name of the key to use with `DROP`. If not then you need to use a better `WHERE` clause to find the key.

Comment: it just give me a bunch of long list

Comment: on my database, the fk is named exactly the same as my commands, under the key